# Where I can study some job shop scheduling by course (video )?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, modeling, scheduling

I am seeking the help  to know where I can study the job shop scheduling Heuristics or using solver
by some course/video as I see some of books and papers hard to understand .

It is hoped that the course will include the update scheduling theory, algorithms, system introduction.

Comment: You could find many related videos on YouTube or other hosts. Please noted that, to understand the scheduling theory and it's application you will need to try it in scratch from the basic concepts then, go to the advanced topic. Please, Remember that many of the videos would not be useful if you do not study before that. 

Comment: "Scheduling" (Pinedo, 2012) https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781489990433 that's a book, but it's rather easy to read